# Uncaught TypeError: info.tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers-3

Below is part of my code thats giving the above error: info.tooltip is not a function. I want to hover on point on map that gives me feature value. I tried a lot and i am newbie in js. Your help would appreciated.

```
var info = $('#info');
info.tooltip({
  animation: false,
  trigger: 'manual'
});

var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
  info.css({
    left: pixel[0] + 'px',
    top: (pixel[1] - 15) + 'px'
  });
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (feature) {
    info.tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', feature.get('features'))
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
  } else {
    info.tooltip('hide');
  }
};
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        info.tooltip('hide');
        return;
    }
    displayFeatureInfo(map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent));
});
```

Comment: Did you include bootstrap library which provides the tooltip functionality?

Comment: Here's a working example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/button-title.html Make sure all dependencies are properly loaded.

Comment: yes i have added bootstrap 3.3.6.